# How do I modify AWS cloudwatch metrics for memory?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a cluster of Elastic Beanstalk instances running Wordpress. RAM utilization is high, around 93% because of some plugins that we're running (a different issue altogether). However, every time one of the instances hits 90+% RAM utilization it kicks the instance into a "degraded" state and kicks it out of the cluster.

I can't for the life of me find a way to modify this RAM utilization check. Ideally I'd be able to bump the RAM utilization threshold up to 95% or so....how do I change this metric, disable it, or remove it altogether?

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the elastic beanstalk Health screen. I may have jumped to conclusions assuming it's a Cloudwatch metric but the concept is still the same...how do I up the threshold?

Of particular note, the instance status and the message beneath it.

[image]

Comment: When you say "it kicks the instance into a degraded state", what is "it"? Can you see an alarm in CloudWatch? What makes you think that CloudWatch is involved?

Comment: Hi John, I may have jumped to conclusions assuming it's a Cloudwatch metric, so I updated the post with a screenshot of the health screen in the Elastic Beanstalk environment for clarity. Note the state of the instance and the message.